# CollectionViewCell is going out of the bound of CollectionView in iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview, iphone-x

I have a collectionViewCell with full width. 
Everything works fine in every devices except in iPhone X.

The collectionViewCell goes out of the bounds of collectionView. I have set `clipsToBounds` **false**.

The result for iPhone X is:

[image]

And the result for other devices is:

[image]

Comment: Is your collectionView using custom layout ?

Comment: Nope. I am using flowLayout and set some properties according to my need.

Comment: try to use UIEdgeInsets in flowlayout